# Is the space of spherical vectors always one (or zero) dimensional?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, harmonic-analysis

For a real semisimple Lie group, $G$, and a maximal compact subgroup $K$, and an irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of $G$, let $H_\pi^K$ be the subspace of vectors fixed by $K$. Is the dimension of $H_\pi^K$ always not greater than one?

Comment: This is trivial

Comment: @PastorDoctorMartinSsempa not as trivial as your rep

Comment: HAH my main has 60k rep. you're just a 2k noob.